# is it possible in netsuite

Tags: sql, netsuite

I have created a saved search in netsuite showing all the open sales and purchase orders for a stock line.
I want to have a running total at the end which takes on hand stock, either plus or minus the transaction line, then on the next entry down show the calculated field from row 1 plus/minus current. So:

Current on hand = 150

```
              Qty      Running Total
```

Sales Order       -50            100
Purchase Order    350            450
Sales Order       -10            440
Sales Order       -20            420

Any help much appreciated!!!

Comment: Please demonstrate some basic understanding of the tool you're using by posting what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'd be able to do this with just a search, although there may be some creative solutions out there for running totals.

I think it could be done with a suitelet for sure, and the results could be displayed in a grid or exported via CSV or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick to creating running totals in a Netsuite Saved Search, as described in this blog posting:

http://blog.prolecto.com/2015/05/26/solving-the-netsuite-cumulative-saved-search-tally-challenge/

I have successfully used this technique to create a SOH running total report, as follows:

**Search Type** - Transaction

**Criteria:**

- *Account* is
- *Posting* is true
- *Quantity* is not 0

**Results:**

- *Date*
- *Main Line Name*
- *Document Number*
- *Type*
- *Formula Numeric* (Label = Running Total, Formula = "SUM /* comment */ ({quantity}) OVER(ORDER BY {internalid} ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND
  CURRENT ROW)")

**Available Filters:**

- *Item*
- *Location* (Show In Filter Region = Y)

I've set this up as a Sublist View that appears on Inventory Items.